# CSS class dependent on parents in Joomla template

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I'm quite fresh in with CSS so that I wasn't sure how to name title properly so feel free to change it.

I am editing [this](https://github.com/gsuez/joomla-master-bootstrap) Joomla template to show vertical menu in left column (template has defined only vertical menu).
[Here](https://github.com/gsuez/joomla-master-bootstrap/blob/master/style/style.css) is css file which defines `.menu` class.
When I put menu in module in left column, elements are floating to left what is defined [here](https://github.com/gsuez/joomla-master-bootstrap/blob/master/style/style.css#L337) 
In module manager I added Menu Class Suffix `nav nav-pills nav-stacked` but `nav-stacked` doesn't override floating.

Page source for horizontal menu

```
<!--Navigation-->
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse"></a>
                <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li class="item-109 current active"
```

Page source for vertical menu

```
<!--Left -->
<div id="sidebar" class="span3">
    <ul class="menu nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="item-109 current active"></li>
        <li class="item-110"></li>
        <li class="item-102"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my idea how to make it - I want to make .menu class to be child of `navbar`. If I understand well inheritance in CSS by doing something like this `.navbar > .menu {...}` if `.menu` class will occur somewhere deep in `.navbar` then its elements will float to left (and have other properties), if not, this statement `menu nav nav-pils nav-stacked` will "produce" vertical menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to write [this](https://github.com/gsuez/joomla-master-bootstrap/blob/master/style/style.css#L337) code like this

```
.menu > li {
    border-left: 0 solid #F2F2F2;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*float: left;*/
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 0 1px 0 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar .menu > li {
    float: left;
}
```

now menu elements will float to left when they will be included in `navbar` class